# how to convert char ** to delphi?

Tags: delphi

I think `char **` mean `ppansiChar` but i don't know how to use it after and the purpose. I have this function

```
char **MagickGetImageProfiles(MagickWand *,const char *,size_t *),
```

that i translate like this :

```
function MagickGetImageProfiles(wand: PMagickWand; const pattern: pAnsiChar; const number_profiles: pSize_t): ppAnsiChar;
```

it's work, however i don't know what to do now with the result as ppansiChar :( why not simple pansiChar ? so maybe i m wrong to use it as ppansichar ? normally MagickGetImageProfiles must return you an array or somethink like this because in number_profiles it's return the number of profiles returned

Comment: Quite simple: a PPAnsiChar is a pointer to a PAnsiChar. Usually this means there is an array of PAnsiChar and the PPAnsiChar points to the first element of it. If you increment a PAnsiChar, it goes forward by the size of an AnsiChar. If you increment a PPAnsiChar it goes forward by the size of a PAnsiChar. That is why a PPAnsiChar is returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a pointer to an array of strings. Personally I'd declare the function like this:

```
function MagickGetImageProfiles(
    wand: PMagickWand; 
    pattern: pAnsiChar; 
    out number_profiles: size_t
): ppAnsiChar; cdecl;
```

Call it like this:

```
var
  i: Integer;
  number_profiles: size_t;
  profiles, p: ppAnsiChar;
... 
profiles := MagickGetImageProfiles(wand, pattern, number_profiles);
// error checking goes here, as described by API documentation 
p := profiles;
for i := 0 to number_profiles-1 do begin
  Writeln(p^);
  Inc(p);
end;
MagickRelinquishMemory(profiles);
```

You could equally set `{$POINTERMATH ON}` and write it like this:

```
var
  i: Integer;
  number_profiles: size_t;
  profiles: ppAnsiChar;
... 
profiles := MagickGetImageProfiles(wand, pattern, number_profiles);
// error checking goes here, as described by API documentation 
p := profiles;
for i := 0 to number_profiles-1 do
  Writeln(profiles[i]);
MagickRelinquishMemory(profiles);
```

Comment: BTW did you see Rudy's answer to your environment variable question?

Comment: yes, @rudyveltuis make a very good example so i don't know, but me i continue to think that in the imagemagick dll the getenvironmentvariable return only the value that was set before the dll was loaded (because the error i receive is only raise after calling getenvironmentvariable when it's return null ... maybe they cache the environment variable or they start another process outside the dll (or even worse cache the exception?), i don't know. but anyway this demonstrate that is always more safe to call setenvironementVariable before to load the DLL.

Comment: No it doesn't demonstrate that at all. That particular dll appears to cache the value of the environment variable. Forcing you to set it before loading. But GetEnvironmentVariable behaves as documented, as I told you. Programming is hard enough without throwing away fact and making things up.

Comment: when i will have time i will debug this c++ dll to know exactly what is it doing with the environment variable, just to satisfy my curiosity.

Comment: in the meantime, i have a very strange problem with your code, under win64, MagickGetImageProfiles return me the pointer $D67F3DA350 in profiles and when i do p := profiles; i have EintOverflow with message "integer overflow" :( i can understand why, on win64 pointer are int64 so why i have such error ?

Comment: @davidheffeman, it's ok i found, it's was because number_profiles is declared as size_t (unsigned) and when we do for i := 0 to number_profiles-1 do ... then off course we have EintOverflow if number_profiles = 0 ... compiler raise the exception in p := profiles; but it's must be in the next row